# No sound on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, audio

I have a problem on my notebook (MSI E-620) running Ubuntu Natty Narwhal x86. When I installed it there was just output, when I plugged my headphones in. The speakers in my notebook do not play anything. 
I tried a lot - now I don't have a listed sound device in Audio-Settings.

The following error appears every time I try to install alsa-driver:

```
root@andre-EX620:/home/andre/Downloads/alsa-src/alsa-driver-1.0.8# ./configure 
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking for current directory... /home/andre/Downloads/alsa-src/alsa-driver-1.0.8
checking cross compile... 
checking for directory with kernel source... /lib/modules/2.6.38-11-generic/build
checking for directory with kernel build... 
checking for kernel version... 0.0.0
checking for GCC version... ./configure: eval: line 3547: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./configure: eval: line 3547: `my_compiler_version=4.5.2-8ubuntu4)'
```

But the Audio-devices are there..

```
root@andre-EX620:/home/andre/Downloads/alsa-src/alsa-driver-1.0.8# lspci | grep -i Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
06:00.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc RV620 Audio device [Radeon HD 34xx Series]
```

Any suggestions?

**Solution:**

I solved the problem by executing the following lines:

```
su root
vi /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf #Am Ende 'options snd-hda-intel model=3stack-6ch-dig', bzw. eine Option von hier einfügen: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Soundkarten_konfigurieren/HDA?redirect=no#Beispielkonfigurationeneinfügen

add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-alsa-driver-modules-$(uname -r)
alsaconf
restart -r now
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if recompiling the driver is the best way for you to get sound, but I think I can get you past the error in `configure`. The script was clearly not tested with “exotic” version strings. It would be worth notifying the authors of this issue. The problematic line is

```
eval $versionvar="$ac_compiler_version"
```

What's going on here is that `eval` is evaluating a string composed of the variable name, an equal sign and the string to assign. This is wrong: it should be evaluating a string composed of the variable name, an equal sign and a shell fragment to generate the string to assign. In other words, the quoting is wrong. This is the right way to do it:

```
eval $versionvar=\"\$ac_compiler_version\"
```

The same fix should be applied to all the uses of `eval` in `configure.in`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- append the following line in the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

  ```
  options snd_hda_intel model = STAC9227
  ```
- reload alsa

  ```
  2.alsa force-reload
  ```
- play a song